# SQL Table Data Import Settings for Date Format

Tags: sql, date

[SQL Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6fzZ.png)

Hi as per this picture link I am importing this table but what should the correct date format be? Will %m/%d/%Y work?

Thanks

Comment: Give the field the proper datatype in your database - date, not string.  Format simply won't matter.

Comment: Hi Dan, my Column Name Date (Has  Datatype as DATETIME) but still shows Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect datetime value) Any idea why?  Thanks

My CSV date is of this format: 10/6/2017

Comment: Varies across databases and import tools.  More info on what technologies you are using would help.

Comment: The sample date you gave is ambiguous.  I suggest editing your question by adding a tag for your database engine, and describing exactly how you are attempting to execute your import.